# Активация input при нажатии на клавишу

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Всем привет. Я, так называемый, новичок в реакте и мне нужна помощь с довольно простым вопросом.
Мне нужно при нажатии на определённую кнопку активировать input (чтобы появилась возможность в нём писать)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import './css/Chat.css'

import ChatMessageList from './elements/ChatMessageList'

const Chat = function () {

    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

    onkeydown = event => {
        if(event.key === 't' || event.key === 'T')
            setActive(!isActive);
    }

    return (
        <div className="chat">
            <ChatMessageList />
            <input type="text" name="chat__text__input" style={{display: isActive ? "block" : "none"}}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p8k81h?file=src%2FApp.js)

Только не забудьте удалить лисенер после размонтирования компонента.